# Google Play App Reviews can't show App Version code

Tags: android, google-play

I have released an app on play store, and have received some reviews. In google play developer console, I could not see the version of app in few of the reviews. 
[image]

does anyone know why **App version: --** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because user has downloaded more than 1 version by his/her devices.
So in user's account, they can't detect that he/she has more than 1 version, therefore ,the app version column shows -- instead.